# Python: Dataclass that inherits from base Dataclass, how do I upgrade a value from base to the new class?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

How can I upgrade values from a base dataclass to one that inherits from it?

Example (Python 3.7.2)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str 
    smell: str = "good"    

@dataclass
class Friend(Person):

    # ... more fields

    def say_hi(self):        
        print(f'Hi {self.name}')

friend = Friend(name='Alex')
f1.say_hi()
```

prints "Hi Alex"

```
random_stranger = Person(name = 'Bob', smell='OK')
```

return for random_stranger "Person(name='Bob', smell='OK')"

How do I turn the random_stranger into a friend?

```
Friend(random_stranger)
```

returns "Friend(name=Person(name='Bob', smell='OK'), smell='good')"

I'd like to get "Friend(name='Bob', smell='OK')" as a result.

```
Friend(random_stranger.name, random_stranger.smell)
```

works, but how do I avoid having to copy all fields?

Or is it possible that I can't use the @dataclass decorator on classes that inherit from dataclasses?

Comment: Maybe it's simplier to create a method `def become_friend(self): return Friend(self.name, self.smell, other_parameters)` of `class Person`?

Comment: not yet familiar with dataclasses but have you tried mutating the class?  rs.__class__ = Friend.  works well (StateMachine pattern) on class designed for equivalence.

Comment: @JLPeyret That sounds like a good recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are asking for is realized by the [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), and can be implemented in python classes straight forwardly using the `@classmethod` keyword.

Just include a dataclass factory method in your base class definition, like this:

```
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    smell: str = "good"

    @classmethod
    def from_instance(cls, instance):
        return cls(**dataclasses.asdict(instance))
```

Any new dataclass that inherit from this baseclass can now create instances of each other<sup>[1]</sup> like this:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Friend(Person):
    def say_hi(self):        
        print(f'Hi {self.name}')

random_stranger = Person(name = 'Bob', smell='OK')
friend = Friend.from_instance(random_stranger)
print(friend.say_hi())
# "Hi Bob"
```

---

<sup>[1] <sub>It won't work if your child classes introduce new fields with no default values, you try to create parent class instances from child class instances, or your parent class has init-only arguments.</sub></sup>

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74184041/1546600 for why this answer breaks when fields themselves are dataclasses

Comment: this doesn't show the case where `Friend` has extra attributes, what happens then?

Answer (score 4):

You probably do not want to have the `class` itself be a mutable property, and instead use something such as an enum to indicate a status such as this. Depending on the requirements, you may consider one of a few patterns:

```
class RelationshipStatus(Enum):
    STRANGER = 0
    FRIEND = 1
    PARTNER = 2

@dataclass
class Person(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    full_name: str
    smell: str = "good"
    status: RelationshipStatus = RelationshipStatus.STRANGER

@dataclass
class GreetablePerson(Person):
    nickname: str = ""

    @property
    def greet_name(self):
        if self.status == RelationshipStatus.STRANGER:
            return self.full_name
        else:
            return self.nickname

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f"Hi {self.greet_name}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    random_stranger = GreetablePerson(full_name="Robert Thirstwilder",
                                      nickname="Bobby")
    random_stranger.status = RelationshipStatus.STRANGER
    random_stranger.say_hi()
    random_stranger.status = RelationshipStatus.FRIEND
    random_stranger.say_hi()
```

You may want, also, to implement this in a trait/mixin style. Instead of creating a `GreetablePerson`, instead make a class `Greetable`, also abstract, and make your concrete class inherit both of those.

You may also consider using the excellent, backported, much more flexible [`attrs`](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) package. This would also enable you to create a fresh object with the `evolve()` function:

```
friend = attr.evolve(random_stranger, status=RelationshipStatus.FRIEND)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of setting in `Person` the `metaclass=ABCMeta`? The class `Person` is still directly instantiable.

Comment: You are right. In order to make it uninstantiable, one must add an `abstractmethod`, and then an exception is thrown upon attempt at instantiation. I don't know if I agree with requiring an `abstractmethod`, and I might see it as an omission. But python tends to be non-agressive with respect to type errors, so it could be a matter of the python philosophy. I would leave it in for the clarity of intention, and probably also not add an abstractmethod unless it represents part of the universal interface of `Person`. In this case, maybe `say_hi()` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

`dataclasses.asdict` is recursive (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict)),
so if fields themselves are dataclasses, `dataclasses.asdict(instance)` appearing in other answers breaks. Instead, define:

```py
from dataclasses import fields

def shallow_asdict(instance):
  return {field.name: getattr(instance, field.name) for field in fields(instance)}
```

and use it to initialize a Friend object from the Person object's fields:

```py
friend = Friend(**shallow_asdict(random_stranger))

assert friend == Friend(name="Bob", smell="OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

`vars(stranger)` gives you a dict of all attributes of the dataclass instance `stranger`. As the default `__init__()` method of dataclasses takes keyword arguments, `twin_stranger = Person(**vars(stranger))` creates a new instance with a copy of the values. That also works for derived classes if you supply the additional arguments like `stranger_got_friend = Friend(**vars(stranger), city='Rome')`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    smell: str


@dataclass
class Friend(Person):
    city: str

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f'Hi {self.name}')


friend = Friend(name='Alex', smell='good', city='Berlin')
friend.say_hi()  # Hi Alex
stranger = Person(name='Bob', smell='OK')
stranger_got_friend = Friend(**vars(stranger), city='Rome')
stranger_got_friend.say_hi()  # Hi Bob
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `vars` to get to attributes of a dataclass, `dataclass.asdict` is better. `vars` will include init-only and class variables, and doesn't work if `__slots__` are used to store the attributes, all of which is bad to not support. Which is why `dataclass.asdict` exists.

Comment: `dataclass.asdict` does not work in my use cases as it converts the child dataclasses recursively (doc: "dataclasses, dicts, lists, and tuples are recursed into."). My dataclasses usually have child dataclasses that should stay dataclasses.

Comment: True, I can see how it wouldn't work for your case then.