# populate dataclass instance from other dataclass instance

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a scenario where I've two dataclass which share some command keys. Let's say

```
@dataclass
class A:
    key1: str = ""
    key2: dict = {}
    key3: Any = ""
```

and class B

```
@dataclass
class B:
    key1: str = ""
    key3: Any = ""
    key4: List = []
```

Both of this class share some key value. Now I want to assign those common key value from class A to to class B instance.

One way I know is to convert both the class to `dict` object do the process and convert it back to dataclass object. But from what I know sole purpose of dataclass is to effectively store data and manage. I believe there is some better approach.

Expected Input and Output

```
# State of dataclass A while B is not initialized
A(key1: "key1value", Key2: {"a": "a"}, key3: [1,2])
# State of B should be
B(key1: "key1value",key3: [1,2], key4: [])
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) . - try to implement a solution; come back and ask a specific question if you run into problems.

Comment: Worth looking at this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824893/python-dataclass-that-inherits-from-base-dataclass-how-do-i-upgrade-a-value-fr) that deals with dataclassess that inherit from one another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `signature` to get all the attributes of your class, then `getattr` to check if keys have the same name, and finally `setattr` to change the value of `classB`, something like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from inspect import signature
from typing import Any, List, Dict

def main():
  instanceA, instanceB = A("key1value", {"a": "a"}, [1,2]), B()
  attrsA, attrsB = signature(A).parameters, signature(B).parameters

  for attr in attrsA:
    if attr in attrsB:
      valueA = getattr(instanceA, attr)
      setattr(instanceB, attr, valueA)

@dataclass
class A:
  key1: str = ""
  key2: Dict[str, str] = field(default_factory=dict)
  key3: Any = ""

@dataclass
class B:
  key1: str = ""
  key3: Any = ""
  key4: List = field(default_factory=list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Instances before assign:

```
A(key1='key1value', key2={'a': 'a'}, key3=[1, 2])
B(key1='', key3='', key4=[])
```

After:

```
A(key1='key1value', key2={'a': 'a'}, key3=[1, 2])
B(key1='key1value', key3=[1, 2], key4=[])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a method to your class, you can do it for any class and have it for A to B or B to A.

The problem I see with *signature* is that if you make any change in ****init****, for example having for B the class A as parameter, it will not work anymore.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields
from typing import Any

@dataclass
class A:
    key1: str = ""
    key2: dict = field(default_factory=dict)
    key3: Any = ""

    def set_keys(self, other):
        self_fields = list(map(lambda x: x.name,  fields(self)))
        for _field in fields(other):
            if _field.name in self_fields:
                setattr(self, _field.name, getattr(other, _field.name))

@dataclass
class B:
    key1: str = ""
    key3: Any = ""
    key4: list = field(default_factory=list)

    def set_keys(self, other):
        self_fields = list(map(lambda x: x.name,  fields(self)))
        for _field in fields(other):
            if _field.name in self_fields:
                setattr(self, _field.name, getattr(other, _field.name))

a = A(key1="key1value", key3=[1, 2])
b = B()

b.set_keys(a)
```

Result:

```
A(key1='key1value', key2={'a': 'a'}, key3=[1, 2])
B(key1='key1value', key3=[1, 2], key4=[])
```