# How to create a dataclass child instance from a parent's instance?

Tags: python

I have the following `dataclass` use-case:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class A:
   x: int = 0

@dataclass 
class B(A):
   y: int = 0

a = A(x=5) 
# what would a flatten implementation be?
b = B(flatten(a)?, y=6)
```

how to accomplish this use-case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Dataclass that inherits from base Dataclass, how do I upgrade a value from base to the new class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824893/python-dataclass-that-inherits-from-base-dataclass-how-do-i-upgrade-a-value-fr)

Comment: thanks but not completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade the solution I linked in a comment by passing additional arguments to `from_instance` method:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class A:
    x: int = 0
    
    @classmethod
    def from_instance(cls, instance, **kwargs):
        return cls(**asdict(instance), **kwargs)

@dataclass 
class B(A):
    y: int = 0

a = A(x=5) 
b = B.from_instance(a, y=6)
```

If you want to be able to pass/override values of the base class, you can do the following:

```
...
    @classmethod
    def from_instance(cls, instance, **kwargs):
        args = asdict(instance)
        args.update(kwargs)
        return cls(**args)
...

a = A(x=5) 
b = B.from_instance(a, x=3, y=6)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! what happens when `b = B.from_instance(a, x=2, y=6)` ? will x be 5 or will it be 2

Comment: The class method is the "correct" approach, especially when logic more complicated than unpacking a dict is necessary to generate the correct arguments  for instantiating the class.

Comment: @SkyWalker I think it will lead to the error of "multiple values to the keyword x". To avoid that you'll need to do simple preprocessing, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych amazing! good stuff! thanks a lot!

Comment: the `asdict` call goes into an endless loop … what could it be?

Comment: while replacing `todict(instance)` with `instance.__dict__` works

Answer (score 1):

## Use `.__dict__` and unpacking

You can create a function `flatten()` such as:

```py
def flatten(dtc: dataclasses.dataclass) -> dict:
    return dtc.__dict__
```

Then, you can [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the resulting dict in the `B` instantiation: `B(**flatten(a), y=6)`.

```py
import dataclasses


def flatten(dtc: dataclasses.dataclass) -> dict:
    return dtc.__dict__


@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    x: int = 0


@dataclasses.dataclass
class B(A):
    y: int = 0


a = A(x=5)
b = B(**flatten(a), y=6)
print(a, b)  # A(x=5) B(x=5, y=6)
```

**Notes: this comply with the design you asked, but the class method approach is recommended, see @Yevhen answer.**

Comment: awesome! thanks a lot!